# Difference between "void main" and "int main

Tags: c

I study C both from textbooks and websites. Somewhere the sample codes begin the program execution by "void main" and somewhere they begin the function with "int main". What's the difference, really? They both give the same result. Is there anything that makes them slightly  different? If so, please mention what does "void" does, and what "int" does.

Comment: Who downvoted my question?? Why???

Comment: void functions returns nothing, int functions must return int..

Comment: it's difference between return type if you use int main you will return integer value before close main function but when use void you not return anything.

Comment: No I didn't copy any question. I just gave my one.

Comment: "please mention what does "void" does, and what "int" does" Finding a C book or tutorial too difficult?

Comment: As a beginner, you can treat them as equivalent. The program will do the same stuff. The difference is the return value that is provided to the operation system. If you start your program on command line, after program termination you can access the return code. If the returned code is zero, it indicate that the program run successful (this will also be returned if you use the `void` signature). All other values indicate an error in the program.

    ./runVoidMain
    echo $?
    -> 0
    ./runIntMainWithReturnZero
    echo $?
    -> 0
    ./runIntMainWithReturnOne
    echo $?
    -> 1

Comment: I have books that use only one of the either ways. No book explained that matter.

Comment: Hey guys can you vote for undeleting this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493309/total-number-of-lines-in-notepad-or-sublime?noredirect=1#comment50950505_31493309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int main()` and the `void main()` all do the same, which is process the main process of the program.

`void main()` it means that the functions main() does not return a value.

The difference is `int main()` is the only right way of calling it, since every program, when called, returns an "error message" that the OS interprets, in which case, closing the program with a return 0; tells the process calling your program that it ended without a problem.

Comment: It's perfect. It is useful for me.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. **THANKS**!!!

Comment: Hey guys can you vote for _undeleting_ this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493309/total-number-of-lines-in-notepad-or-sublime?noredirect=1#comment50950505_31493309

Comment: In void main no need to use return. ' void main(){}'. void means null. But using int means you should return some int value..otherwise it will show  the following error **"Function expects to return some value"**..

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI standardization of C says that the main function must return an integer. But if you program embedded systems, for instance, then you will use `void main`. Please se this question for elaboration: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: I would upvote if you hadn't added that line about embedded systems, because it's sorely misleading.

Comment: Could you plz elaborate on this matter??

Comment: @DevSolar How is it misleading? The format of main on an embedded system is not specified by the standard.

Comment: And what does the actually **relevant** ISO standard say?

Comment: @Olaf Depends on which version of the standard, and if it is a hosted or freestanding system, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).

Comment: @Lundin: The standard states that in a hosted system there shall be a function `main`, and it shall return `int`. There are no specifications as to what a freestanding system does, so stating that "you will use `void main`" is misleading.

Comment: @Lundin: There is only one valid version of the standard and that is commonly called "ISO", just because the ANSI is a national organisation. And, as you already commented, the standard does not specify a signature for freestanding implementations; not `void main(void)` as the answer states..

Comment: @DevSolar: Not exactly. The standard goes one step further and states that a [freestanding](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1p1) environment may use any signature it wants.

Comment: Standards aside, I have yet to see an embedded system where the form of main was not `void main (void)`. Systems that don't have a main() at all, but just a reset vector are usually written in pure assembler.

Comment: Plz can you stop this fighting!!

Comment: @Lundin: [OSDev BareBones kernel tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones). You asked. ;)

Comment: Hey guys can you vote for undeleting this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493309/total-number-of-lines-in-notepad-or-sublime?noredirect=1#comment50950505_31493309