# Is there a real difference between int main() and int main(void) in C?

Tags: c

### Preface:

This is probably gonna be marked as a duplicate, and I understand, but I am asking this, because I feel other answers may not be quite as clear. In fact, the closest answers that I have found that make the most sense to me are this one: [from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864316/difference-between-void-main-and-int-main) and this one: [from 2013,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928520/so-what-does-return-0-actually-mean) about `return 0;`

I have very little programming experience--I messed around with Java several years ago, and kinda figured out what I needed to copy and paste to edit the program I was playing with, and I have written a simple program in python, and I played around with Scratch in School. But, I have finally decided to sit down, learn a language, C, and just roll with it.

So, what I would like to ask, is, am I interpreting this right? because, if so, then it can be said there is, for most intents and purposes, no difference between `int main()`, with no arguments, and `int main(void)`.

### Actual Importance:

To summarise my current understanding:

1. If `int main()` is used, then you should add at the end `return 0;`, to signify the programs termination.
2. Though possible, it is improper to use `int main()` and not use `return 0;`, as many compilers may not recognise this.
3. If `int main(void)` is used, then it is unnecessary to add `return 0;`.

In plain English, would this be said as a good, and/or accurate explanation?

### Examples:

```
/*
 * Program example using scanf, printf, and int main() with no variable
 * This program reads a string from the user
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char name[10];                /* number in square brackets is for max characters in name */
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);            /* scanf will read input until it sees blank space, then stop */
        printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
        return 0;
}
```

vs.

```
/*
 * Program example using scanf, printf, and int main(void)
 * This program reads a string from the user
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        char name[10];                /* number in square brackets is for max characters in name */
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);            /* scanf will read input until it sees blank space, then stop */
        printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}
```

Comment: `return` is about the return type, not the argument.

Comment: Answer (Yes), though somewhat a matter of semantics, in C a function with empty `()` takes an *indeterminate* number of arguments, while `(void)` specifies *zero* arguments.

Comment: All 3 points in `Actual Importance:` are wrong. 1) You don't need to add `return 0` inside `int main()`.  2) It is ok to use `int main()` without `return 0`. 3) It is not necessary to add `return 0` inside `int main(void)`. `In plain English` In plain English, if `main` returns an `int`, there is no need to write `return 0`. No matter what is inside the parameter list. `int main(/*anything  here*/) { /* always returns 0 by default */ }`

Comment: A good start would be to compile both sets of code and look at it in assembly.

Comment: You are confused about argument list, but you asking about function return value. You should pick one thing.

Comment: @KamilCuk That makes a little more sense, so my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Hm.. Maybe the standard will clear things up. The exact rule about this is [C11 5.1.2.2.3p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3p1): `If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, .... reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0`. If it returns `int` and the execution reaches the closing `}` in `main`, it acts as `return 0`.

Comment: as @Stefan said it's not about the arguments in this situation. Maybe you're confused about `void main()` or `void main(void)` concept.

Comment: There are very strong stylistic differences.  `int main()` looks like you are either writing C++, or you are living in 1987.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Taking input in the form of questions like that is very 1987. `WOULD YOU LIKE TO PLAY A GAME? (Y/N)`

Comment: I wonder if in 2059 there will still be new threads on this topic

Comment: I VTC as unclear because the title doesn't match the question body  (in reality there is a difference between the two, but that difference has nothing to do with return statements)

Answer (score 3):

> If `int main()` is used, then you should add at the end `return 0;`, to signify the programs termination.

Mostly true.  This is good practice, although not strictly necessary, as we'll see.

> Though possible, it is improper to use `int main()` and not use `return 0;`, as many compilers may not recognise this.

Mostly false.  For some time now, and as a special case unique to a function named `main()`, if you do not supply a return statement, the compiler is required to arrange that `main` implicitly return 0.

An old compiler may still require the `return 0;`, and behave badly if it is omitted -- although the malfunction is typically minor.  Also a compiler so old as to not comply with this requirement will certainly have many other, more significant compatibility issues to worry about.

> If int `main(void)` is used, then it is unnecessary to add `return 0;`.

Correct, but misleading.  There is no difference whatsoever between `int main()` and `int main(void)` in this regard.  It is also true (per the above) that if `int main()` is used, it is unnecessary to add `return 0`.

Comment: I would say that it's not good pratice. It's just noise.

Comment: to be specific instead of "Mostly"  : it was required in C89 and is redundant in C99 and later

Comment: @M.M And if you ever need to compile your code on a C89 compiler (not very likely) then just activate warnings (which IS good practice)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `int main()` doesn't specify a prototyped declaration for `main`. As a *definition* of the function, the two are equivalent, and define the function in mutually compatible ways. However, `int main()` introduces less compile-time information into the scope.

In C (unlike C++), `main` is allowed to recurse. Thus we can consider the following silly program:

```
int main(void)
{
   main(42);
}
```

because `main` is declared completely, the `main(42)` call is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic. If we change the program to:

```
int main()
{
   main(42);
}
```

then the function hasn't changed: it's still one that takes no arguments. But that information is not declared as part of the `main` identifier's type information, and so the call doesn't require a diagnostic. (If translated and executed, it invokes undefined behavior; but that may happen even if there is a diagnostic.)

This is an old style, before C had function prototype declarations, which were first standardized in 1989's ANSI C and in widespread use before that.

Answer (score 0):

The latest standard allows you to ommit the `return 0` statement. As for the protype of `main()`, there are 3 equally variants:

```
int main()
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

An empty parameter list in C means that you can pass as many parameters as you want but the function will not care about any of them. Specifying a `void` parameter list means that you explicitly have to pass **no** arguments or you will get an error.

While the standard only explicitly accepts versions #2 and #3, version #1 also works because the OS passes the arguments for version #3 and your function will not care about them.

Hope my answer was clear enough.

Comment: So, if I am understanding that right, if you add `void`, then you cannot add arguments when you use gcc, make, etc., that specifically affect the program in some way, shape, or form, presently above my understanding?

Comment: "An empty parameter list in C means that you can pass as many parameters as you want but the function will not care about any of them." - this is not correct according to the standard

Comment: @M.M it is UB, but this is what happens in practice.